# iCheck library: CSS styling issue

Tags: jquery, css, icheck

I'm using the [iCheck](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) library for a couple of radio buttons. I'd like the buttons and their labels to display all on the same line (see jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dfbyu/)), but am having trouble styling the elements appropriately.

The issue is (I think) that iCheck "*wraps each input with a div, which may be customized by you or using one of the available skins*" (quote taken from the '*Simple Usage*' section of the [iCheck](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) page).

### What I've tried

-- Overriding just the display property in the library's CSS as follows:

> .iradio_flat-orange {   display: inline !important; }

Result - the radio boxes disappear altogether.

-- Wrapping the labels in a single `<span style="display: inline">`

Result - no change, radio buttons display as per the jsFiddle.

Does anyone have an idea how I can style the radio buttons appropriately?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dfbyu/1/

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Please post comment as answer and I'll accept it. I hadn't thought of using <ul>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ul li` list to get it working, wrap your `input` and `label` with `li` and style it with `display: inline-block;`

**[See this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfbyu/1/)**

HTML

```
<p>Are you sure you want to have your details removed from our marketing list?</p>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="iCheck">
        <label>Yes</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="iCheck">
        <label>No</label>
    </li>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```